# asp.net OWIN save the JSON post data

Tags: asp.net, json, httprequest, owin, httpresponse

I have the setup a test command line app using self hosting OWIN.
I have one test controller and this works as expected to deliver a static home page plus two values in JSON format on a get request.

I'm using the JsonFormatter to format all results.

I would like to read JSON data into it from a post request.
I can send an accepted message response but the data is always null when read.

```
// POST api/values 
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string myString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Terry Tibbs");
        Console.WriteLine(myString);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
```

I'm using Postman in Chrome to post data as below but myString is always blank.

```
POST /api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a966fa36-010d-3e2b-ad66-2f82dcb155ed
{
   "myString": "This is new"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> ### Using [FromBody]
>
> To force Web API to read a **simple type** from the request body, add the
>   **[FromBody]** attribute to the parameter:
>
> ```
> public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string myString) { ... }
> ```
>
> In this example, Web API will use a media-type formatter to read the
>   value of `myString` from the request body. Here is an example client
>   request.
>
> ```
> POST api/values HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Fiddler
> Host: localhost:8080
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 13
>
> "This is new"
> ```
>
> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header
>   to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is
>   "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string **(not a
>   JSON object)**.

Comment: Thanks very much. Google is no help if you don't not what you're searching for. :)